# Why does my function does not work anymore

Tags: python, pandas, function, drop

I am a student, just starting with python and I have a problem with the .drop function in pandas.

1. I have created some dummies (for many variables, here I give only 1 example)
2. Now I want to get rid of the initial columns / variables but the function doesn't work.

```
dummy = pd.get_dummies(leads['MainTariffInsuranceGroupSF'], prefix ='MainTariffInsuranceGroupSF')

leads = pd.concat([leads,dummy], 1)
```

```
#leads = leads.drop(['LeadCreation_Weekday','MainTariffInsuranceGroupSF','LeadCreation_DecadeInMonth', 'Nationality', 'Language', 'AgeGroupStandard', 'OccupationType', 'Region'], axis=1, implace=True)
```

I also have to say: I don't get any error. Variables are just not removed. And the last time (a few days ago, when I worked on this jupiter notebook this same lines of code worked without a problem.

Comment: `leads = leads.drop(...` and `implace=True` isn't a good combo.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a minimum working example (MWE)?

Did you work through the official [doc of the pd.dataframe.drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) function?

The documentation states for inplance: *inplacebool, default False
If False, return a copy. Otherwise, do operation inplace and return None.*

Did you try to run the code in a Python file (without notebook)?

There is a typo in the line: **implace -> inplace**

```
leads.drop(['LeadCreation_Weekday','MainTariffInsuranceGroupSF','LeadCreation_DecadeInMonth', 'Nationality', 'Language', 'AgeGroupStandard', 'OccupationType', 'Region'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

or

```
leads = leads.drop(['LeadCreation_Weekday','MainTariffInsuranceGroupSF','LeadCreation_DecadeInMonth', 'Nationality', 'Language', 'AgeGroupStandard', 'OccupationType', 'Region'], axis=1)
```

should do the trick. This is after seeing the comment below your initial post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Kind of new to contributing to SO. Updated the answer with solution proposals. I hope that is sufficient for an answer?